# installshield Installer deletes folder from my documents

Tags: installation, installshield, setup-project

I have two installers, one will create folder("ProjectRDE") in mydocuments using Installshield Limited Edition --> Application Files --> [PersonalFolder]. As expected when i run the exe, it created "ProjectRDE" folder in MyDocuments.
Another installer(which is also installs the same project output) will not have any folders in [PersonalFolder].(i consider the second installer as Upgrader.exe)
When i execute the second installer it deleted the "ProjectRDE" folder from MyDocuments. But i have not create any custom actions. Even I cant mark the folder as "Permanant", as the installer is only limited edition.
My query is, why this "ProjectRDE" is getting deleted, even i have not mentioned it in the second installer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I exactly understand your situation entirely, but if your "Upgrader.exe" is actually performing a major upgrade, then it triggers an uninstall of the previous version, before installing the upgrade.